# kafka-clients 3.1.2 node disconnected messages frequently

Tags: apache-kafka

after upgrading kafka-clients from 3.0.1 to 3.1.2, the application logs frequently
[Producer clientId=producer-8] Node 301 disconnected.
but our producer all are working fine. is the info message harmful to our application? is there any tuning to be done?

upgrade from 3.0.1 to 3.1.2